# Copy Sheet1 of multiple workbooks to one new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 99 workbooks in a folder. I want to copy sheet1 from each into a new workbook. It doesn't matter what order as long as each workbook/sheet1 goes onto a new worksheet in the destination workbook.

I have written a code, and tried to sample other codes. No matter what it will only copy sheet1 of the first 10 workbooks.

How can this work on all the workbooks in the folder? My goal is to get the sheets together so I can merge certain cells into a summary sheet.
I put this code into a module on my destination workbook.

```vb
Sub combineWorkbooks() 
    Path = "C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Invoices Jones UK Group\Paid\JJ0001-JJ0099\" 
    fileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls") Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=Path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next sheet
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir() Loop 
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this should prevent any issues trying to copy multiple sheets with the same name into the workbook.

```vb
Sub combineWorkbooks()
    Dim Path, fileName, sheetNum As Long, sheetName As String
    
    Path = "C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Invoices Jones UK Group\Paid\JJ0001-JJ0099\"
    fileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    
    Do While fileName <> ""
        With Workbooks.Open(fileName:=Path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True)
            sheetName = .Worksheets(1).Name
            sheetNum = 1
            'if a worksheet with the same name already exists, add
            ' an incrementing number until the name is unique
            If WorksheetExists(sheetName) Then
                Do While WorksheetExists(sheetName & sheetNum)
                    sheetNum = sheetNum + 1
                Loop
                .Worksheets(1).Name = sheetName & sheetNum 'rename if required
            End If
            'copy to end of sheets
            .Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
            .Close
        End With
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

If you're still getting only 10 files then maybe it's an issue with the file names/extensions?

Edit - try listing all of the files:

```vb
Dim Path, fileName
Path = "C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Invoices Jones UK Group\Paid\JJ0001-JJ0099\"
fileName = Dir(Path & "*")
Do While fileName <> ""
    Debug.Print fileName
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
```

What output do you get?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, thank you so much for responding (again) to my question. I have run this new code, and it is till only copying the same 10 workbooks (JJ01 to JJ10). How can i resolve the issue with the names/extensions please. The file does have a long name (save as JJ01 - project title) but i don't want the file name to be save in new workbook. To save as sheet 1/2/3 is fine.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, thank you. I inserted the recent code you detailed and this did not run anything at all. Not even an error code?

Comment: `Debug.Print` outputs to the immediate pane (show with Ctrl+G) in the VB editor...   https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/debug-print-immediate-window/

Comment: Ive put a screenshot/image link in my original question, but basically it lists every worksheet i would like putting into the new/destination worksheet

Comment: Do you get an error message when you try the first code I posted?  It's useful to say so if that's the case...

Comment: In @TimWilliams second block of code change `fileName = Dir(Path & "*")` to `fileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls")` and run it again. Do you get 10 filenames return or all of the ones you want? I suspect most of your files are xl* ie xlsx xlb etc. Edit: I just looked at your screenshot, this is indeed the case. Just change `*.xls` to `*.xl*` and you should be good.

Comment: @DanDonoghue - that was why I posted with just `*` - so it would be obvious if there were files with different extensions

Comment: Yes I was trying to show them how only the 10 will return when it is the same as what they have in their main code block

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams i get (with first code you posted) Error 104 Application-defined or object defined error.

Comment: @DanDonoghue I have just inserted that change into Tim's first code, and I get an error (Microsoft Visual Applications x 400), again its copied the 10 sheets

Comment: Sorry @TimWilliams I did respond and say it didn't do anything, not even an error code.

Comment: One which line of code (from the first block I posted) did you get an error?

Comment: Maybe the files contain the same sheet names? Meaning it actually loops over all of the 99 files, but overwrites the sheets as of the sheetnames.

Comment: Ok I've made an update.  *If you get an error* when running it, it's useful to say so right up front, and tell us what the error *message* is (more so than the number) and which line of code is triggering it.

Comment: thanks for your response @TimWilliams the new code appears to work but still only brings the first 10 sheets in? Then it gives me an error '400' so it isn't appearing on any line in the code. it just gives me the error after loading 10 workbooks to new workbook. I aso tried changing it to  "*.xl*" as suggested by Dan, this does the same thing but gives error Application-Defined or Object-Defined error. (again doesn't appear to be on any line of code?)

Comment: Are you clicking "Debug" when the error message pops up?

Answer (score 0):

It was a file name extension, as you thought.

I now have this working.

```vb
Sub CombineFiles()
     
    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim WS              As Worksheet
     
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Invoices Jones UK Group\Paid\JJ0800-JJ0899" 'Change as needed
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
            WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next WS
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub
```